# ImportError when using import as

Tags: python, python-import, python-sphinx

I have the following layout for my project:

```
chemcoord/
    __init__.py
    cartesian_coordinates/
        xyz_functions.py
        cartesian_class_main.py
        ...
    ...
docs/
    sources/
        conf.py
        cartesian_coordinates.rst
        src_xyz_function1/
            chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions.view.rst
            ...
        ...
    ...
```

My package has a `setup.py` script, was installed via `pip install -e` and is available in the `PYTHONPATH`. Nevertheless I also put:
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(u'../../'))` into the Sphinx `conf.py` file.

In the `__init__.py` I import:

```
from chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.cartesian_class_main import Cartesian
from chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates import xyz_functions
# the import of pew is just for testing purposes
from chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates import xyz_functions as pew
```

One function in `xyz_functions.py` is called e.g. `view`.
And if I do this in my Ipython console all functions are defined:

```
 import chemcoord as cc
 cc.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions.view
 cc.xyz_functions.view
 cc.pew.view
```

The following sphinx code in the `cartesian_coordinates.rst` file should document the `Cartesian` and the `xyz_functions`

```
Cartesian coordinates
===================================



.. currentmodule:: chemcoord


The ``Cartesian`` class which is used to represent
a molecule in cartesian coordinates.

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_Cartesian

    ~Cartesian



A collection of functions operating on instances of ``Cartesian``.

.. currentmodule:: chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_xyz_functions1

    ~isclose
    ~read
    ~write
    ~view


A collection of functions operating on instances of ``Cartesian``.

.. currentmodule:: chemcoord

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_xyz_functions2

    ~xyz_functions.isclose
    ~xyz_functions.read
    ~xyz_functions.write
    ~xyz_functions.view


A collection of functions operating on instances of ``Cartesian``.

.. currentmodule:: chemcoord

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_xyz_functions3

    ~pew.isclose
    ~pew.read
    ~pew.write
    ~pew.view
```

I generate the stub `rst` files via `sphinx-autogen` and they look like:

```
chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions.view
==================================================

.. currentmodule:: chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions

.. autofunction:: view
```

Now the really strange thing is, that 
the parts with: `chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions` and `chemcoord.Cartesian` are documented, but I get an ImportError for the documentation parts with:
`chemcoord.xyz_functions` and `chemcoord.pew` and they are not documented. The stub `rst` files were created by `sphinx-autogen` in all cases.
Does anyone have an Idea how to tackle this problem?

The intended usage for the end user is:

```
 import chemcoord as cc
 cc.xyz_functions.view(...)
```

For this reason I want to document it with `xyz_functions` in the namespace of `chemcoord`.

Edit 1 (Clarifying because of answer of @LaurentLaport):

Also if I write in the `cartesian_coordinates.rst` file the following, it still does not work:

```
Cartesian coordinates
===================================



.. currentmodule:: chemcoord


The ``Cartesian`` class which is used to represent
a molecule in cartesian coordinates.

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_Cartesian

    ~Cartesian



A collection of functions operating on instances of ``Cartesian``.

.. currentmodule:: chemcoord

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: src_xyz_functions2

    ~xyz_functions.isclose
    ~xyz_functions.read
    ~xyz_functions.write
    ~xyz_functions.view
```

Comment: If your ``chemcoord`` library is installed in your virtualenv when you run ``sphinx-build``, you don't need to put:
``sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(u'../../'))`` into the Sphinx ``conf.py`` file.

Comment: I just mentioned it because ``sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(u'../../'))`` solved 80 % of the questions about ImportErrors regarding Sphinx

Comment: I found the chemcoord project on GitHub. I cloned it and ran "make html" in the docs directory. There were no errors; I only got a few warnings related to cross-references.

Comment: Thank you very much for this effort. You probably used the master branch. I refactored a lot of code in a side branch after which my problems in the documentation emerged. The current branch is called ``doc_bug_search``. 
I also set up my read-the-docs webpage in order to track this branch. The problem can be seen there (http://chemcoord.readthedocs.io/en/doc_bug_search/cartesian_coordinates.html). I will change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an Issue on the sphinx webpage where they gave me a working solution. I am still not sure, if it is a clean solution though.

The trick was to fake the module system with the following lines in the `__init__.py` file:

```
import sys
sys.modules['chemcoord.xyz_functions'] = xyz_functions
```

The explanation is [straightforward](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3713):

`import Y` in module `X` makes `Y` an attribute of `X` module. It does not mean converting `Y` to `X.Y` module.
On the other hand, `import X.Y` tries to load `X.Y` module, not `Y` attribute of `X` module.
As a result, it failed to import.

Answer (score 0):

The packages `chemcoord.xyz_functions` and `chemcoord.pew` are only references (or aliases) to the package `chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions` which is already documented.

This is why it doesn't work.

Comment: (See my edited answer) If I understand the logic correctly, it should work, if I only include ``chemcoord.xyz_functions``, which it does not.

Comment: The important thing is that I really want to document it as ``chemcoord.xyz_functions`` and not ``chemcoord.cartesian_coordinates.xyz_functions`` because of end user workflow.